# Inner automorphisms acts as identity on Hochschild homology

Tags: homological-algebra, noncommutative-geometry, hochschild-cohomology, hochschild-homology

Let $A$ be a unital algebra and $u \in A$ be an invertible element. Let us consider $u_n(a_0 \otimes a_1 \otimes ... \otimes a_n):=ua_0u^{-1} \otimes ua_1u^{-1} \otimes ... \otimes ua_nu^{-1}$. Then $(u_n)_n$ is a chain map and it induces an arrow $u_*$ in Hochschild homology.

> Why $u_*$ is identity?

I came across the following formula: for each $n$ one puts $h_i:A^{\otimes(n+1)} \to A^{\otimes(n+2)}$ where $i=0,1,2,...,n$ and
$$h_i(a_0 \otimes ... \otimes a_n)=(a_0u^{-1} \otimes ua_1u^{-1} \otimes ... \otimes u \otimes a_{i+1} \otimes ... \otimes a_n).$$
Then it is claimed that $h:=\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^ih_i$ is a chain homotopy between $id$ and $u_*$.

I don't really see how to interpret these dots in the formula for $h_i$. I think that having a right formula+informtation that it really works would be enough for me to conclude the result.

EDIT: This is based upon Lemma 3.5.1. in "Basic Noncommutative Geometry" by Masoud Khalkhali
LATER EDIT: According to the book of Loday, these $h_i$ constitute the so called *presimplicial* homotopy between the map $u_n$ and the indentity. Once you have presimplicial homotopy the formula $h:=\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^ih_i$ defines homotopy between maps $u_n$ and $id$ so the induced maps in homology are the same. I just wanted to know additionally, whether the following is true: if I have an algebra map $f:A \to A$ which induces identity in Hochschild homology, is it true that $f$ induces also identity in Hochschild *co* homology (in general)?

Comment: Could you give a reference to where you saw this formula?

Comment: My initial guess (but this is spceulative!) is that one could try to set up some projective resolution of A by A-bimodules, in such a way that the usual comparison lemma for projective resolutions constructs the desired homotopy. But I haven't thought about this in any detail

Comment: I edited my post and gave the reference

Comment: I think there's a typo in the formula. My initial guess would be that the $u$ term should be $ua_i$, and that the dots in between should be $ua_ju^{-1}$, for $1 \leq j \leq i$, but I haven't checked. Conceptually, my guess is that there's a nice abstract explanation: conjugation obviously acts as the identity on $HH_0$, so it should act as the identity on $HH_\bullet$ since Hochschild homology is a derived functor. (This isn't completely precise, but it sounds reasonable to me.)

Comment: The formula, with general coefficients, is in 4.1.2 of Loday's "Cyclic Homology" (page 115 (and for cyclic homologies in the next proposition 4.1.3))

Comment: @PeterSamuelson: No, the $u$ is fine. The tensorand just before the $u$ is $ua_iu^{-1}$; this should hopefully explain what the $\cdots$ are.

Comment: I edited my post in order to ask additional question. I hope it is fine, since I didn't want to start another topic.